# How can I do numbering with a hanging indent to the left into the page margin?

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, numbering, indentation

I am compiling some solutions to textbook exercises, and I am trying to do so in the style of the book. The way the book does it is that the body of each exercise appears unindented, left-aligned, where one would expect it to be, at the left margin, but the number for the problem is right-aligned to the left of that.

An impression of the result is this:

```
     This is the left margin.

  1. This is the first problem.

       This is the first paragraph of the first solution, which has a normal first-line
     indent.
       This is the second paragraph of the first solution...

       This is a new paragraph following a line break, still in the first solution.

       This is the second page of the first solution.

  2. This problem follows.
     ...
 10. This is the tenth problem.
```

I would be equally happy with the following:

```
This is the left margin.

 1. This is the first problem.

 2. This problem follows.
     ...
10. This is the tenth problem.
```

The numbers are in boldface and wrap around every chapter (so there are multiple 1's, 2's, etc.), and solutions are (to be) typed in between.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use an `enumerate` list? As far as I understand this would give you the second layout. And then it would be a matter of changing some list parameters (which I'd have to look up, but I'm sure someone here knows) to get the first one.

Comment: I honestly don't know enough about the flexibility of the enumerate command (or enumitem package) to be sure. Both the problem statements and solutions can be multi-paragraph, multi-display affairs, and I thought \item got ticked off when you tried to include multiple paragraphs in an item.

Comment: Lists are robust enough that you can't break them that way.

Comment: see also [How can I number paragraphs (and sections) in the margin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55197/579)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

enumerate might be one solution. In that case I would use the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to customize the list according to the requirements.

For longer solutions, you could better customize the sectioning. For this, I would use [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec). Here's a short example for such hanging headings and formatting like in your comment below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\normalfont\slshape}{\makebox[2em][r]{\textbf{\thesection.}}}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-3em}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
This is the left margin.
\section{This is the first problem.}
This is the solution.
\section{This problem follows.}
\addtocounter{section}{7}
\section{This is the tenth problem.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here `\makebox` puts the label into a box of fixed width and aligned to the right. Other values cause the overhanging into the left margin.

Comment: Thanks. So by fiddling with the \titleformat I could make it, say, the same size as the rest of the type, but slanted? What if I wanted the problem numbers bold, with following periods? Since the problem statements now seem to be sections, can the \section environment, with this package, accommodate multi-paragraph contents, with displays embedded, etc. I would then only want the first line of the problem/section unindented. Occasionally the problems are more expository than anything and go on for half a page.

Comment: @jdc: No problem, I will edit my example accordingly.

Comment: It isn't seeming to like multi-paragraph sections. The line break throws it off.  Also, is there a way to specify a weird section number like 23.5?

Comment: Sorry, that isn't what I meant to type, before. I hit "return" to start a new paragraph and instead submitted a sentence fragment.

Comment: @jdc: Sure, it should be possible. But it's hard to post solution code in comments as answer to further questions in comments, and it makes the website unclear. Better post a further question as a new question instead of developing a comment thread. It's perfectly fine to break down a complex problem into several well-defined questions.

Comment: Okay, it just feels like I'm bogging down the site with bad questions.

Comment: @jdc: The site bases on questions and develops a knowdledge base building on questions. Any good formulated meaningful question is a good contribution to the site. So feel free to post questions.