# How do I make a hanging indent for numbered paragraphs?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

The code I have is:

```
    1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat \
```

But as you can see in this output:

[image: ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNZv0.png)![ss]
The part that says "mod" is not aligned with the first word, "Lorem." I would like all subsequent parts of the paragraph like the letter 'm' in "mod" to be directly under the letter 'L' in "Lorem" including any future numbered paragraphs (there will be some other stuff in between the paragraphs). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Perhaps the `enumerate` environment is what you'd like?

Comment: This answer is quite complete and could help you to get what you want http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55198/31058

Comment: What is the difference between what you want to do and the `enumerate` environment?

Comment: I posted an answer, but withdrew it when I saw it matched Fran's comment.  The `enumerate` environment is what you most likely want.

Answer (score 3):

Others have mentioned enumerations, but perhaps have overlooked the request for material between items.  An out-of-the-box solution for this is provided by the `enumitem` package, where there is the possibility of labelling an `enumerate` with a `series` name.  Following instances can then use `enumerate` together with `resume`

```
 \begin{enumerate}[series=numpars]
 \item ...
 \end{enumerate}

 ....

 \begin{enumerate][resume=numpars]
 \item ...
 \end{enumerate}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lipsum} %For dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{enumerate}[series=numpars]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{enumerate}[resume=numpars]
\item \lipsum[4]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

If you would like a dedicated environment `numpar` for this without the need for `resume` or `item` then you can use the following code, which produces the same output as above.  The idea is to add a toggle to keep track of whether this is the first instance or not and pass either `series` or `resume` to the list constructor.  Additionally, it has been set-up with a dedicated list type `numparmain`, that could be customised further (via standard options in `enumitem`) to adjust indentation or label style.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,etoolbox}
\newlist{numparmain}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[numparmain]{label=\arabic*.}

\newtoggle{firstnumpar}
\toggletrue{firstnumpar}
\newenvironment{numpar}{\iftoggle{firstnumpar}%
      {\begin{numparmain}[series=numpars]}%
      {\begin{numparmain}[resume=numpars]}%
    \global\togglefalse{firstnumpar}%
    \item\ignorespaces}%
  {\end{numparmain}}


\usepackage{lipsum} %For dummy text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{numpar}
 \lipsum[2]
\end{numpar}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{numpar}
  \lipsum[4]
\end{numpar}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution (which does not put the number in the margins).  You can adjust the size or \parindent, \parkskip etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{.1in}

\newlength{\RightColumn}
\setlength{\RightColumn}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\RightColumn}{-\parindent}

\newcounter{ParNum}

\newcommand{\NumPar}[1]% #1 = = paragraph
 {\stepcounter{ParNum}
 \noindent\makebox[\parindent][l]{\arabic{ParNum}}
 \parbox[t]{\RightColumn}{#1}\par}

\begin{document}

\NumPar{This is my first paragraph, but I need to add more
words until I have enough to test the hanging indentation.}

\NumPar{This is my second paragraph, but I need to add more
words until I have enough to test the hanging indentation.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why not use a list construct?

Comment: For most problems there are multiple possible solutions.  Pick the one that appeals to you.  You could even do this in a tabular.

Comment: Yes of course but almost every latex display is a list `center`, `quote`, `verbatim` apart from its extensive support for actual lists such as `enumerate`, `itemize` it seems strange to suggest this list is numbered "by hand" in this way.

Comment: I'm an old plain TeX user.  (I still use \eqno.)  I can do it using a counter, but do you want them in \arabic, \aleph, \Aleph, \roman or something more exotic?

Comment: To put it another way, sometimes autonumbering is more or a hindrance than a help.

Comment: Very rarely:-), apart from cross referencing, the list environment also takes care of many other things notably page breaking and the space between the items (using `\parbox[t]` aligns the top row but hides the position of the baseline of the last line (as it is `\vtop`) so TeX can not compensate for any descenders in the last line of the item.

Comment: OTOH, how many times have you seen questions here where they want to use a package but they NEED it to do something it wasn't designed to do.