# A simple section exercise section

Tags: sectioning, numbering

What I want seems pretty simple, but I was not able to find a satisfactory answer.

What I want is something like this

```
\section{Foo}
A bunch of definitions, theorems, remarks, etc.
\begin{exercise}
\ex\label{ex:foo:t1} Show that this is that.
\begin{ans}
This is that by casual observation.
\end{ans}
\ex Show that is this
\begin{ans}
Just reverse the answer to exercise \ref{ex:foo:t1}.
\end{ans}
\end{exercise}
```

The output should be something like:

1 **Foo**

A bunch of definitions, theorems, remarks, etc.

**Exercises**

1. Show that this is that.

   Ans: This is that by casual observation.
2. Show that is this

   Ans: Just reverse the answer to exercise 1.

I also need some flexibility in numbering. For example, with a few changes to the preamble, the output could be:

1 **Foo**

A bunch of definitions, theorems, remarks, etc.

**Exercises For Section 1**

1.1 Show that this is that.

Ans: This is that by casual observation.

1.2 Show that is this

Ans: Just reverse the answer to exercise 1.1.

Comment: Packages `exsheets`, `answers`, `probsoln` etc. can do this, I think

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you mind putting it in form of an answer with a concrete example of how to achieve this using those packages?

Comment: Perhaps later on, but I think other users will be faster than I and most likely provide a better solution then because they do know more than I do about those packages

Comment: Most of the complexity in itemize and enumerate comes from embedding layers.  A single layer enumerated environment is pretty trivia to set up.  All you need is a counter and hanging indentation. see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134408/how-do-i-make-a-hanging-indent-for-numbered-paragraphs/134430#134430

Comment: Please always post a ***complete*** example. As it stands, it is almost impossible to determine how best to implement the desired formatting of `\section{Foo}` because it depends on your class and on any packages you are using to customise the format of sectional headings.

Comment: Like @ChristianHupfer says this is doable with little effort with `exsheets` (with a slightly different syntax). I'll post an answer showing how if you want…

Comment: Definitely doable, and I'll post an answer demonstrating it later :) One question: do you wish the answers to be separated from the questions, e.g in a separate section at the end of the document?

Comment: Thank you. Either way will do. My preference is to have the answer right after the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation using the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) to do some of the lifting with formating:

[image: screenshot]

In the code below, we have:

```
\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[exercise]{label*=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*,before={\subsection*{Exercises}}}
```

This defines a list-like environment called `exercise`.

The next bit,

```
% copy \item into \ex
\let\ex\item
```

defines `\ex` as `\item`.

Finally, we define an `ans` environment:

```
% a simple ans environment
\newenvironment{ans}{\par Ans:}{}
```

Here's the complete code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}

% use the enumitem package to ease the list-like
% definition of the exercise environment
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[exercise]{label*=\arabic*.,ref=\arabic*,before={\subsection*{Exercises}}}

% copy \item into \ex
\let\ex\item

% a simple ans environment
\newenvironment{ans}{\par Ans:}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
A bunch of definitions, theorems, remarks, etc.
\begin{exercise}
    \ex\label{ex:foo:t1} Show that this is that.
    \begin{ans}
        This is that by casual observation.
    \end{ans}
    \ex Show that is this
    \begin{ans}
        Just reverse the answer to exercise \ref{ex:foo:t1}.
    \end{ans}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

Regarding your requirements for numbering flexibility, if you write:

```
\setlist[exercise]{label*=\thesection.\arabic*.,ref=\thesection.\arabic*,before={\subsection*{Exercises}}}
```

then you obtain:

[image: screenshot]

If you reach a point in the future when you need to separate the answers from the questions, then you might like to look at the [`answers`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/answers) package; here's a link to questions tagged with related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/answers.