# How to number (on the left margin) paragraphs instead of lines?

Tags: numbering, paragraphs, line-numbering

I am aware of package lineno for row numbers, but my line numbers may change due to English language editing but my paragraphs will likelly not: is it possible to number (on the left margin) paragraphs instead of lines, so I can refer to some text as “Section 2.2, paragraph 3″ ?

I saw [How can I number paragraphs (and sections) in the margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55197/how-can-i-number-paragraphs-and-sections-in-the-margin) but section numbers and paragraph numebers are put together there, while I am looking to something more like lineno, where on the margin I have just parapraphs numbers instead of lines.

Comment: Are you talking about the command `\paragraph` or automatic counting of paragraphs after empty lines? How do you want to reference in the second case? In the first case: Your link does provide everything you need. Just kick the redefinitions of the Sections out.

Comment: @Antonello Can you upload a picture what you want? A counter for all paragraphs, starting with 1 and ending at the end of the document with 867? Or should the counter be reseted to 1 after each section? What in case of subsections, subsubsections and so on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `parano` package mentioned in that other posting, together with a couple of fixes and customisations as follows.  Now updated to work with `hyperref`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parano}% http://www.sci.usq.edu.au/staff/braithwa/parano.sty
%\usepackage{hyperref}

%Fixes to parano.sty
\makeatletter

\newcommand{\paranospace}{\hfill}% Introduced for more flexible customisation

\renewcommand{\@parano}{%
  \everypar{\setbox0\lastbox% Fixes first paragraph indent problem
    \refstepcounter{parano}%
    \hbox to \paranoboxwidth{\prepara\theparano\paranospace}\postpara}}

\def\@@parano[#1]{\setcounter{parano}{#1}\addtocounter{parano}{-1}%
   \@parano}% To avoid code duplication

\makeatother

%Customizations for this example

\renewcommand{\prepara}{\hss}
\renewcommand{\postpara}{\hspace{\parindent}\ignorespaces}
\renewcommand{\paranospace}{\quad\hfill}
\setlength{\paranoboxwidth}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\parano

\section{Test}

\lipsum[1-2]

Here is a paragraph to be labelled.\label{mypara}

\lipsum[3]

The labelled paragraph was \ref{mypara}.

\end{document}
```

If you want the paragraphs just to be numbered within each section then add

```
\renewcommand\theparano{\arabic{parano}}
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{parano}{section}\makeatother
```

to the preamble.

Comment: I am sorry my question wasn't clear. This is the effect I wanted to give to the document, with the added code to the preamble to reset the counter at each section and subsection. Thank you.

Comment: On my real document using "\usepackage{hyperref}" sends back the paragraph lines within the document margins. Why and how could I avoid it ?

Comment: I have updated the code - the first two statements in the `\everypar` need to be in the opposite order when using `hyperref`, without it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: is parano still the way to do this? I can't find a live link for this package

Comment: A copy of the package seems to be available at https://github.com/HugoAreias/DRAW--includes-DREQL-/blob/master/Manual/parano.sty

Comment: That version on Github doesn't seem to work

Comment: @JonathanPrieto-Cubides I have just downloaded it again and tested on the above code and it works fine for me with `parano.sty` in the same directory as the tex file.

Comment: Oh, so it must be then something in my setup, thank you for testing it. I'll try it again. One thing, can it be loaded with the book document class?

Comment: Indeed, for the book class it works as well. ;) I had a different issue.

Comment: @AndrewSwann I just noticed that I'm having numbering for chapter titles and section titles the same as I have for paragraphs, I'm using the book documentclass btw. Any idea how to fix it?