# What's the best class, package or template for a game rulebook?

Tags: packages, templates, document-classes

I'd like to write a game rulebook, so I need an environment that lets me divide the text in articles and subsections—something like this ([link](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf)), except that hopefully it will look much prettier in LaTeX. Does anybody know if there is already a package or template that was thought exactly for this kind of documents?

Comment: Finding a package for this proved surprisingly difficult. Have a look at the answer to this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263759/220875 I think this is exactly what you need.

Comment: Then maybe this can be of help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129211/220875

Comment: Then finally here is also an approach to numbered paragraphs: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215344/220875

Comment: For completeness you might look at the outlines and booklet packages.