# Replicating output

Tags: fonts, paragraphs

How can I replicate the following output.

1. How can I get the paragraph numbering, and
2. which is the font family used, for example, which font is in the title.

I really appreciate any hint.

[image]

**Update**

To answer (1), one possible solution is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215344/15256. At the moment of writing, paragraph numbering works using the approach described there.

To answer the second question, I suspect is some variant of Libertine in the body text. I'm not 100% sure. After using `pdffonts` as David has suggested in the comments, I got the following table.

- The section title "background" font seems to be "Artemisia".
- The body text font is "Palladio", I guess.

```
name                                           type              emb sub uni prob object ID
---------------------------------------------- ----------------- --- --- --- ---- ---------
RKQMKN+URWPalladioL-Roma                       Type 1            yes yes no           11  0
REYGRC+URWPalladioL-Ital                       Type 1            yes yes no           12  0
BVTZJM+GFSArtemisia-Regular                    Type 1            yes yes no           22  0
JXKDUB+GFSArtemisia-Bold                       Type 1            yes yes no           66  0
ESIPNF+CMSSBX10                                Type 1            yes yes no   X       67  0
JBFQGH+URWPalladioL-Roma-Slant_167             Type 1            yes yes no          119  0
CZEJUL+CMSY10                                  Type 1            yes yes no   X      152  0
CARRUQ+PazoMath                                Type 1            yes yes no   X      171  0
SOSTRQ+CMR10                                   Type 1            yes yes no   X      172  0
FFYOJC+CMSS10                                  Type 1            yes yes no   X      173  0
KLLCOA+MSAM10                                  Type 1            yes yes no   X      176  0
JNTAYX+BBOLD10                                 Type 1            yes yes no   X      177  0
BDEJWY+CMTT10                                  Type 1            yes yes no   X      207  0
NLCOTU+URWPalladioL-Bold                       Type 1            yes yes no          262  0
CVNJDW+CMMI10                                  Type 1            yes yes no   X      272  0
FEWUZZ+PazoMath-Italic                         Type 1            yes yes no   X      287  0
BYXUKI+EURM10                                  Type 1            yes yes no   X      316  0
AXQXCC+CMEX10                                  Type 1            yes yes no   X      317  0
VAUDZG+BBOLD7                                  Type 1            yes yes no   X      318  0
ZAXYBZ+LINE10                                  Type 1            yes yes no   X      384  0
AXLWSJ+wasy10                                  Type 1            yes yes no   X      757  0
LWBNRC+stmary10                                Type 1            yes yes no   X     1090  0
SZMZGR+CMBX10                                  Type 1            yes yes no   X     1106  0
GICGZR+CMSS8                                   Type 1            yes yes no   X     1315  0
MWYJNZ+CMTT8                                   Type 1            yes yes no   X     1316  0
WHPMRG+MSBM10                                  Type 1            yes yes no   X     2766  0
XDXTRJ+CMTT9                                   Type 1            yes yes no   X     3228  0
HHHFVR+stmary8                                 Type 1            yes yes no   X     3487  0
```

Comment: Font: Start with a standard font. / Greek letters: use those macros $\alpha$ etc. in a math environment. / Color: there are several ways to change text color. / Italics: use \textit{depends}. / Numbering each and every paragraph: requires some (i.e. many) lines of adapted macros. / Vertical spacing: See next remark. // So all would be found in a big book introducing Latex, like "Einführung in Latex", Herbert Voß (probably only available in German). // I suggest studying such book(s) before trying. Which one do you have?

Comment: Your question is way too broad, and comes across as a "do this for me" question.  You ask about fonts, layout, numbering and referencing styles, colorizing, etc., all in one question.  Narrow it down to a single aspect.

Comment: as always for "what font" questions, do you have the PDF or is that a picture of a book, if you have the pdf you can get the list of fonts using `pdffonts` or the font menu in a pdf viewer.