# How to create an eviroment for questions in which the number of the question is in the left margin and the solution and the question text are aligned?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments

I am attempting to create an environment for questions and solutions. My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcounter{problema}[section]
\newenvironment{problema}[2]
    {\noindent\hspace{-25pt}\makebox[20pt][r]{\refstepcounter{problema}\textbf{\theproblema}}
        \makebox[5pt][l]{}\textbf{\textit{#1}} 
        \newline #2\par\medskip
        \noindent\(\looparrowright\)
    }
    {\bigskip}

\begin{document}
    \begin{problema}{The topic of the problem}
        {The text of the problem}
        The solution
    \end{problema}
\end{document}
```

The result I achieve is:
[image]

How can I make "the topic of the problem", "the text of the problem" and the symbol before "the solution" be aligned (without indentation)?

EDIT: I used `\documentclass{article}`.

Comment: \noindent ? Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I've tried adding some other \noindent besides the ones remaining but they had no effect.

Comment: your code does not work, what documentclass you use?

Comment: I used article, sorry for not putting it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with the number in the margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\newcounter{problema}[section]
\newenvironment{problema}[2]
    {\noindent\llap{\makebox[20pt][r]{\refstepcounter{problema}\textbf{\theproblema}}\hskip5pt}\hspace*{-0.4\fontdimen2\font}%
    \textbf{\textit{#1}}
        %\makebox[5pt][l]{}\textbf{\textit{#1}}
        \newline #2\par\medskip
        \noindent\(\looparrowright\)
    }
    {\bigskip}

\begin{document}

    \begin{problema}{The topic of the problem }
        {The text of the problem.The text of the problem. The text of the problem.The text of the problem. The text of the problem.The text of the problem. The text of the problem.The text of the problem. }
        The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution. The solution.
    \end{problema}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How does this `\hspace*{-0.4\fontdimen2\font}` work?

Comment: `\fontdimen2` is the (average) interword spacing in the current font. The value `-0.4` was found by trial and error.  In theory, it should not depend on the font size.

Comment: Can you see what was wrong in my original code?

Comment: I did not know this command `\llap`, used by Bernard. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tex_commands/llap.htm

Comment: You were just missing that LaTeX inserts some interword spacing between the label and the topic. Some part of it goes into the margin, the rest starts at the left margin.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was considering that LaTeX was going to put all of the boxes I had created one after the other!

Comment: You might be interested by an approach as  a theorem-like structure. The `ntheorem` package defines a `margin` style, which puts the label in the margin.

Comment: I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed you use article documentclass.

Here is a working code.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mathtools} %<--------- why you added this?
\usepackage{amssymb}%<---- I added this

\newcounter{problema}[section]
\newenvironment{problema}[2]
{
\noindent   \refstepcounter{problema}\textbf{\theproblema}
    \noindent \textbf{\textit{#1}}
    \newline #2\par\medskip
    \noindent\(\looparrowright\)
}
{\bigskip}
\begin{document}
    \begin{problema}{The topic of the problem}
        {The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem }
        The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution 
    \end{problema}
\end{document}
```

output: 
[image]

However, I don't think it looks good anyway. Following in what I suggest for you to use.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{mathtools} %<--------- why you added this?
\usepackage{amssymb}%<---- I added this
\newcommand{\addindentation}{\par
    \leftskip=2em
    \noindent\ignorespaces}{%
    \par\medskip}
\newcounter{problema}[section]
\newenvironment{problema}[2]
{\refstepcounter{problema}
\noindent   \textbf{Problem \theproblema. \textit{#1}}
\addindentation
    \newline #2\par\medskip
    \noindent\(\looparrowright\) \textbf{Solution.}
}
{\bigskip}
\begin{document}
    \begin{problema}{The topic of the problem}
        {The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem }
        The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution 
    \end{problema}

    \begin{problema}{The topic of the problem}
    {The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem The text of the problem }
    The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution The solution 
\end{problema}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I also recommend that you check the package `tcolorbox`, you can make much better results using it.

Comment: Good suggestion. Do you know a way to successfully put the number of the problem at the left margin, out of the text area?  The way I tried in my code (using negative \hspace and \makebox) is the one I use to format sections when I want their number on the left margin, like found in some books.

Comment: I can fix it by making the empty box (\makebox[5pt][l]{}) smaller, but the math of what I did in the code should work, as far as I can see.

Comment: tcolorbox is great indeed, but I would like to achieve a model template boxes.

Comment: This question has a solution for numbering in margin https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55197/how-can-i-number-paragraphs-and-sections-in-the-margin. If my answer above answered you question, kindly check it as answered.

Comment: I know this solution, and I do use it for the titles but it cannot be used for the case of a nonnative title, can it?

Comment: Yes you are right, it might not work