# Negative indentation of chapter and section titles

Tags: koma-script, indentation, scrreprt

I would like to align chapter, section, subsection etc. titles as I have done in the table of contents:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    tocindent=-2cm,
    tocnumwidth=2cm]{chapter, section, subsection}

% Errors for chapter, as this does not have an indent option.   
\RedeclareSectionCommands[
    indent=-2cm,
    numwidth=2cm]{chapter, section, subsection}
    
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\end{document}
```

## Table of Contents (Good):

[image]

## Chapter and its sections, subsections (Not good):

[image]

I would like the alignment in the numbering in a Chapter to be the same as in the picture of the table of contents, but could not find a way to do this properly. What I have tried to show in the picture is that all the `Test` titles should be starting from the same vertical alignment line, while the same goes for their numbering in the left margin.

Comment: See: [How to print the heading numbers in the left margin](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_NumbersAtLeftMargin/). The same is [also available in German](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_NumbersAtLeftMargin/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I number paragraphs (and sections) in the margin?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55197/how-can-i-number-paragraphs-and-sections-in-the-margin) esp. [Schweinebacke's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483479/277964).

Comment: @cabohah Almost entirely! I was still wondering about the 2 cm indent to align it with the defined ToC numbering in my MWE. I fiddled around and ultimately got this: 
```\hskip-\marginparwidth\hspace{2cm}``` instead of ```\hskip\marginparsep``` from the answer. However, when I check it using a ´digital' ruler, it does not seem to align perfectly. To the eye it is probably indistinguishable, but it still stings me. Would you recommend editing the question?