# Labels in the left margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

I would like to produce a text with `label`s in the left margin, like a reference list. Labels may have different lengths. One way to do this is to define a negative `\parindent`, as follows:

```
\parindent-12mm
\makebox[12mm][l]{A} text text text   text text text text text   text text text text   text text  text    texttexttexttext  \par 
\makebox[12mm][l]{ABC} text text text   text text text text   text text text text   text text  text    texttexttexttext
```

The purpose of the box is to make the text begin at the left edge of the text column. However, in this way the left edge of the text column won’t be straight, because Tex expands or shrinks spaces evenly along the entire line, including the box. Therefore (instead of the box) I would need, after the label, a command that moves to the left edge of the text column in the same way as a tab command. Is there such a  command?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: this covers the same territory: [How can I do numbering with a hanging indent to the left into the page margin?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8480/579) -- the question doesn't really say that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy with the `enumitem` package. Just define

```
\SetLabelAlign{margin}{\llap{#1~~}}
```

and use it like

```
\begin{description}[align=margin,labelsep=0pt]
  \item[A] text text text
  \item[ABC] text text text
\end{description}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\SetLabelAlign{margin}{\llap{#1~~}}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the margins
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[align=margin,labelsep=0pt]
  \item[A] text text text
  \item[ABC] text text text
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Another solution is to define

```
\SetLabelAlign{margin}{\llap{\makebox[12mm][l]{#1}}}
```

In this way the result will be

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this: (???)

The showframe package is just for to show the position of the margins. It can be removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\setlength{leftmargini}{0pt}
\begin{itemize}

  \item[A] text text text
  \item[ABC] text text text
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is useful; thanks! But I don't understand how the command \SetLabelAlign works. Moreover, with the description environment the text paragraph gets a negative indentation; I don't understand why. But with enumerate the left edge of the text is straight, as I want.

Answer (score 1):

`enumitem` already provides a `right` alignment for labels. Use it with `leftmargin=\labelsep`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the margins
\begin{document}

\begin{description}[align=right,leftmargin=\labelsep]
  \item[A] text text text
  \item[ABC] text text text
\end{description}

\end{document}
```