# Position enumitem label in the right margin

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumitem

This is similar to a tex question but somewhat opposite: [Labels in the left margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223701/labels-in-the-left-margin)

What I would like is for the description (enumitem) in the right column to have the labels in the right margin, similar to have the left column has labels in the left margin.

Current (not quite right)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{paracol}
\SetLabelAlign{margin}{\llap{#1~~}}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the margins
\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{description}[align=margin,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=*,font=\color{gray}]
  \item[A] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  \item[ABC] moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext
\end{description}
\switchcolumn
\raggedleft
\begin{description}[align=margin,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=*,font=\color{gray}]
  \item[A] text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
  \item[ABC] moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext
\end{description}
\end{paracol}



\end{document}
```

[image: minimum reproducible example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `rightmargin` key to typeset a zero width box extending past the column width. I renamed `margin` to `leftmargin` for symmetry.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the margins

\SetLabelAlign{leftmargin}{\llap{#1\enspace}}
\SetLabelAlign{rightmargin}{\rlap{\hspace{\columnwidth}\enspace#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{description}[align=leftmargin,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=*,font=\color{gray}]
  \item[A] text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
           text text text text text text text text text text text text text
           text text text text text text text text text text text
  \item[ABC] moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext
             moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext
             moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext
             moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext
             moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext
\end{description}
\switchcolumn
\raggedleft
\begin{description}[align=rightmargin,labelsep=0pt,leftmargin=*,font=\color{gray}]
  \item[A] text text text text text text text text text text text text text
           text text text text text text text text text text text text text
           text text text text text text text text text text text
  \item[ABC] moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext
             moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext
             moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext
             moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext
             moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext moretext
\end{description}
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image]